# Where can I find bitcoin price charts?

Tags: exchange-rate, charts

I am trying to see some bitcoin charts but looks like all sites are down. Any help?

Comment: http://bitcoincharts.com/ works for me...

Comment: not for me at the moment..

Comment: We recently launched https://pizzacharts.com to provide gorgeous realtime crypto-charts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/mtgoxUSD has historical charts.

These 3 all have 'live' charts:

- http://btccharts.com/
- http://mtgoxlive.com/
- http://bitcoin.clarkmoody.com/

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you should not use Mt. Gox as an indication of the price of Bitcoin.  The price on Mt. Gox is significantly higher than the other exchanges, because sellers must be compensated for the difficulty of getting their money off the site.  Instead, you might use BTC-e for pricing info. Here is the chart you ask for:

http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/btceUSD#rg1ztgSza1gWMAzm1g10zm2g25zvzcv